# Extract json value from facebook jql

Tags: java, json, facebook-fql

how can i get the value `fan_count` , **1st** `message` and `created_time` from the string below.

I have tried the code below, but obviously will not work:

```
facebook_Fan_Count = queryResults.get(0).getString("fan_count");
facebook_post = queryResults.get(0).getString("message");
```

String:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "count",
      "fql_result_set": [
        {
          "fan_count": 732
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "messages",
      "fql_result_set": [
        {
          "message": "Weekly class with Sheikh Hassan on TILAWA \n(implementing tajweed)\n\nEvery Friday after Maghreb\nCommencing 6th December at Daar Ibn Abbas.",
          "timeline_visibility": "normal",
          "created_time": 1386230874
        },
        {
          "message": "SMS SERVICE:\n\nTo keep up to date with events and prayer times at Daar Ibn Abbas please inbox us your name and number.\n\nJazackAllah khier",
          "timeline_visibility": "starred",
          "created_time": 1386022521
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the value for fan_count , 1st message and created_time you can do Json parsing

```
JSONArray ar = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");
```

you can iterate through this data and fetch your 1st message

from the fist iteration you can get the fan_count

```
jsonObject = (JSONObject) ar.get(0);
```

**fan_count** is not a string it is of type long.

so you need to do something like this

```
long count = (Long) jsonObject.get("fan_count");
```

from the second iteration you can get the message and created date

```
jsonObject = (JSONObject) ar.get(1);
String message = (String) obj1.get("message");
long dt = (Long) obj1.get("created_time");
```

Comment: what library for json do you use here

Comment: i get error error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int JSONArray ar = (JSONArray) queryResults.get("data"); when using List<JsonObject> queryResults = facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, JsonObject.class);
                                
                                JSONArray ar = (JSONArray) queryResults.get("data");

Comment: try this
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse("Your String");
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONArray ar = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");

Comment: thank you, although how can i integrate my dynamic string to your code List<JsonObject> queryResults = facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, JsonObject.class);

Comment: Object obj = parser.parse(queryResults); does not work

Comment: error: no suitable method found for parse(List<JsonObject>)
                                Object obj = parser.parse(queryResults); 
    method JSONParser.parse(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; List<JsonObject> cannot be converted to String)

Comment: Ossama i was using json pasing for a String but what you have is a list of JsonObject you need not parse them.